# Opening multiple projects in Intellij Idea, having their own modules

Tags: intellij-idea, module

I have two projects, having their own modules:

```
projectA
  moduleA1
  moduleA2
projectB
  moduleB1
  moduleB2
```

I want to edit both projects at the same time with Intellij Idea. They advice to import one project as a module of another. Ok, let projectA be a module of projectB. I'd like to see the structure:

```
projectA
  moduleA1
  moduleA2
  projectB
    moduleB1
    moduleB2
```

But I get

```
projectA
  moduleA1
  moduleA2
  moduleB1
  moduleB2
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any capability not to unwrap the current project structure?

Answer (score 1):

Not going into the configurations of the classpath and other variables, just simply the file structure; I had the same problem at first when attempting to re-create your scenario. Though it is a simple "over-looked" setting of the modules.

The overall layout is:

[image]

Now when adding another module (in this case "ModuleA3", Intellij will set the default path to: $PROJECT_DIR$/Module3A

[image]

Because of this, Intellij is trying to create this module as a sub-module of the "Top-Level Project"; the solution is somewhat simple, change the path to:
$PROJECT_DIR$/ProjectA/Module3A

[image]

EDIT: I can now post images so I included my originals for this question; I find them easier to see what is going on.

*-Thomas*